# Web Scraping shopee.sg with selenium and BeautifulSoup in python

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Whenever I am trying to scrape shopee.sg using selenium and BeautifulSoup I am not being able to extract all the data from a single page.

Example -  For a search result consisting of 50 products information on the first 15 are getting extracted while the remaining are giving null values.

Now, I know this has got something to do with the scroller but I have no idea how to make it work. Any idea how to fix this?

**Code as of now**

````
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from time import sleep
import csv

# create object for chrome options
chrome_options = Options()
#base_url = 'https://shopee.sg/search?keyword=disinfectant'

# set chrome driver options to disable any popup's from the website
# to find local path for chrome profile, open chrome browser
# and in the address bar type, "chrome://version"
chrome_options.add_argument('disable-notifications')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-infobars')
chrome_options.add_argument('start-maximized')
#chrome_options.add_argument('user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\username\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\Default')
# To disable the message, "Chrome is being controlled by automated test software"
chrome_options.add_argument("disable-infobars")
# Pass the argument 1 to allow and 2 to block
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("prefs", { 
    "profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications": 2
    })


def get_url(search_term):
    """Generate an url from the search term"""
    template = "https://www.shopee.sg/search?keyword={}"
    search_term = search_term.replace(' ','+')
    
    #add term query to url
    url = template.format(search_term)
    
    #add page query placeholder
    url+= '&page={}'
    
    return url

def main(search_term):
# invoke the webdriver
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options = chrome_options)


    item_cost = []
    item_name = []
    url=get_url(search_term)

    for page in range(0,3):
        driver.get(url.format(page))
        delay = 5 #seconds


        try:
            WebDriverWait(driver, delay)
            print ("Page is ready")
            sleep(5)
            html = driver.execute_script("return document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML")
            #print(html)
            soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
            #find the product description
            for item_n in soup.find_all('div',{'class':'col-xs-2-4 shopee-search-item-result__item'}):
                try:
                    description_soup = item_n.find('div',{'class':'yQmmFK _1POlWt _36CEnF'})
                    name = description_soup.text.strip()
                except AttributeError:
                    name = ''
                print(name)    
                item_name.append(name)

            # find the price of items
            for item_c in soup.find_all('div',{'class':'col-xs-2-4 shopee-search-item-result__item'}):
                try:
                    price_soup = item_c.find('div',{'class':'WTFwws _1lK1eK _5W0f35'})
                    price_final = price_soup.find('span',{'class':'_29R_un'})
                    price = price_final.text.strip()
                except AttributeError:
                    price = ''
                print(price)
                item_cost.append(price)
  
        except TimeoutException:
            print ("Loading took too much time!-Try again")
        sleep(5)
    rows = zip(item_name, item_cost)
    
    
    with open('shopee_item_list.csv','w',newline='',encoding='utf-8') as f:
        writer=csv.writer(f)
        writer.writerow(['Product Description', 'Price'])
        writer.writerows(rows)```
````

Answer (score 1):

The issue was that the products that you were trying to scrape load dynamically as you scroll down the page. There may be more elegant solutions than mine, but I implemented a simple javascript scroller, using driver.execute_script (additional resource: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/execute_script-driver-method-selenium-python)

#### Scroller

which scrolls to a tenth of the page's height, pauses for 500 milliseconds, and then continues.

```
driver.execute_script("""
    var scroll = document.body.scrollHeight / 10;
    var i = 0;
    function scrollit(i) {
       window.scrollBy({top: scroll, left: 0, behavior: 'smooth'});
       i++;
       if (i < 10) {
           setTimeout(scrollit, 500, i);
       }
    }
    scrollit(i);
""")
```

Additionally, you had two *for loops*, for item_n in soup.find_all(...), for item_c in soup.find_all(...) that were iterating over divs in the same class. I fixed that, in my code, so that you can get both the price and the name of each item while only using one for loop.

You also had try-except statements (in case there was an AttributeError, i.e. if the items you were finding in soup.find_all were NoneTypes). I simplified those into if statements, like this one

```
name = item.find('div', {'class': 'yQmmFK _1POlWt _36CEnF'})
if name is not None:
    name = name.text.strip()
else:
    name = ''
```

And finally, you were using zip for two different lists (names and prices), to add to a csv file. I combined those individual lists into a nested list in the *for loop*, instead of appending to two separate lists and zipping at the end. This saves a step, though it is optional and may not be what you need.

#### Full (updated) code

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
from time import sleep
# create object for chrome options
chrome_options = Options()
# base_url = 'https://shopee.sg/search?keyword=disinfectant'

# set chrome driver options to disable any popup's from the website
# to find local path for chrome profile, open chrome browser
# and in the address bar type, "chrome://version"
chrome_options.add_argument('disable-notifications')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-infobars')
chrome_options.add_argument('start-maximized')
# chrome_options.add_argument('user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\username\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\Default')
# To disable the message, "Chrome is being controlled by automated test software"
chrome_options.add_argument("disable-infobars")
# Pass the argument 1 to allow and 2 to block
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("prefs", {
    "profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications": 2
})


def get_url(search_term):
    """Generate an url from the search term"""
    template = "https://www.shopee.sg/search?keyword={}"
    search_term = search_term.replace(' ', '+')

    # add term query to url
    url = template.format(search_term)

    # add page query placeholder
    url += '&page={}'

    return url


def main(search_term):
    # invoke the webdriver
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
    rows = []
    url = get_url(search_term)

    for page in range(0, 3):
        driver.get(url.format(page))
        WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "shopee-search-item-result__item")))
        driver.execute_script("""
        var scroll = document.body.scrollHeight / 10;
        var i = 0;
        function scrollit(i) {
           window.scrollBy({top: scroll, left: 0, behavior: 'smooth'});
           i++;
           if (i < 10) {
            setTimeout(scrollit, 500, i);
            }
        }
        scrollit(i);
        """)
        sleep(5)
        html = driver.page_source
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
        for item in soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'col-xs-2-4 shopee-search-item-result__item'}):
            name = item.find('div', {'class': 'yQmmFK _1POlWt _36CEnF'})
            if name is not None:
                name = name.text.strip()
            else:
                name = ''

            price = item.find('div', {'class': 'WTFwws _1lK1eK _5W0f35'})
            if price is not None:
                price = price.find('span', {'class': '_29R_un'}).text.strip()
            else:
                price = ''
            print([name, price])
            rows.append([name, price])

    with open('shopee_item_list.csv', 'w', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        writer.writerow(['Product Description', 'Price'])
        writer.writerows(rows)
```

Comment: Hey! Thank you for the solution. I was actually getting stuck at the lazy loading part and even though I figured out a way to scroll through the page, I was not being able to extract information at the same time.

Comment: Can you suggest any other resources to refer to because I am getting stuck while extracting information at a product level. For example (https://shopee.sg/Dettol-Disinfectant-Spray-Original-Pine-225ml-i.323430152.8014353462) if I try to scrape the number of rating stars or the name of the product, the price or brand it's returning me an empty list. I have no prior experience with javascript and hence I am facing these issues.

Comment: WebDriverWait and some sort of identifier? To get the stars rating, I would use either ```WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "_1mYa1t")))``` which would wait for the element of that *single class* to be located, or ```WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="main"]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]')))``` with xpath. Afterward, use soup to get the text.  You can do the same thing with the other elements you wish to extract. This waits for elements to be found.

Comment: Like to get the name of the product you gave me, https://shopee.sg/Dettol-Disinfectant-Spray-Original-Pine-225ml-i.323430152.8014353462, I could use ```WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "attM6y")))
html = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
for item in soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'attM6y'}):
    name = item.find('span').text
    print(name)
``` to wait for the div element, get the text of the span tag *within* the div element. This gave me: "Dettol Disinfectant Spray Original Pine, 225ml"

Comment: additional resource: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/explicit-waits-in-selenium-python

Comment: Thank you so much! I have managed to extract info from the product page by using WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "page-product"))) and iterating over the URLs I extracted from the category page.